# My laptop got switched off while working in vs code. Can I undo my file changes somehow? Its not connected to git

Tags: visual-studio-code

My laptop got switched off while working in vs code. Can I undo my file changes somehow? It's not connected to git.

Comment: Only if working with the latest edition of VScode. In v1.44.2 one of the features included was `Persisted Undo/redo stack`.